# Searching names with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to return people from a search string that can consist of any variation of a name, such as: 'john', 'john smith', 'smith, john', 'john jason smith', or any other common variation. I can cleanup the string and format as a regular expression if need be.

I am aiming for something similar to this:

```
SELECT firstname, 
       middlename, 
       lastname 
FROM   people 
WHERE  firstname LIKE 'search' 
        OR middlename LIKE 'search' 
        OR lastname LIKE 'search';
```

The problem is that a search string such as 'john smith' will return all **johns** and all **smiths** instead of only **john smith**. Any ideas?

Comment: Dude, in my SQL server, a feature called FULLTEXT Search is available and when it's turned on, you just have to provide the string and it automatically finds whatever words found on your string. Find something that is similar to this in Oracle as this is more efficient. If you don't want to do this. Follow @Carth 's advice. He's right about it. It's the solution I thought and it might be a good idea to manipulate your string using another language before passing the query statement against SQL.

Comment: Check what I came up with below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only return rows that meet all of your supplied criteria then you need to add those filter criteria. There are a couple of ways to do it but you could do something as simple as this:

- Split up your term into the searchable tokens
- Make your search case insensitive by forcing everything to upper case
- Use INTERSECT to only return those rows that match all your tokens
- Be sure to use wildcarding if desired -  In this example token1 = '%JOHN%' and token2 =
  '%SMITH%'

**SQL:**

```
SELECT firstname, 
       middlename, 
       lastname 
FROM   people 
WHERE  ( Upper(firstname) LIKE token1 
          OR Upper(middlename) LIKE token1 
          OR Upper(lastname) LIKE token1 ) 
INTERSECT 
SELECT firstname, 
       middlename, 
       lastname 
FROM   people 
WHERE  ( Upper(firstname) LIKE token2 
          OR Upper(middlename) LIKE token2 
          OR Upper(lastname) LIKE token2 );
```

Comment: You're right here man. I'm trying to figure out how to split the words using SQL only. I've already done something like this a long time ago but with the help of C# to manipulate the original text and split everything into 1 word strings. I use SQL Server for now and it doesn't really matter if it's in upper case or not. I'm not so sure for Oracle, but it should probably be the same.

Comment: @chris_techno25 Oracle is case sensitive by default for string comparison so be careful. If you need to do this routinely I'd stick it in a package but you could create an anonymous code block and split the string into an array, dynamically build the select and execute it through EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. I'll see if I can think of a more straightforward solution but that might be it.

Comment: well thank you very much for that information Sir. I'd be sure to remember that if I ever switch to Oracle. Basic but one of the most overlooked information it is. Thank you.

Comment: This is perfect. I'll dynamically add multiple intersections depending on the number of words or 'tokens' in the search string. (I was hoping to add the ability to search on more fields also) Thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

Try this dude. I tested this against SQL server and it works. Make the necessary change for it to work against Oracle. I've only tested this with 1 field name. Just edit the code so it suits your needs. It's basically @Carth 's solution implemented only using SQL.

```
 DECLARE @stringsearch varchar(255)='stringvalue'
    while CHARINDEX('  ',@stringsearch) > 1            
      begin            
        SET @stringsearch=REPLACE(@stringsearch,'  ',' ')            
      end   
 SET @stringsearch=REPLACE(@stringsearch,' ','%'' AND fieldname LIKE ''%')+'%'''
 DECLARE @sql varchar(max)=''
 SET @sql='SELECT fieldname FROM TableName
 WHERE fieldname Like ''%'+ @stringsearch
 EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: What scripting language are you using, from which the search string is coming from? Or are you purely querying all in on the sql pane?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Thankfully I'm using PHP so I can cleanup the search string as you're doing with a scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

Given your particular requirements (match on any of 'john', 'john smith', 'smith, john', 'john jason smith'), this is what I'd try:

```
SELECT firstname, 
   middlename, 
   lastname 
FROM   people 
WHERE  (firstname || ' ' || lastname) LIKE :search
    OR (lastname || ', ' || firstname || ' ' || middlename) LIKE :search
    OR (firstname || ' ' || middlename || ' ' || lastname) LIKE :search;
```

(I've added parentheses for clarity, although they're not required in this case)